# Burn existing token through new contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, tokens

How can I burn a token that already exists with no burnable functionality inside its smart contract? Can i create a new contract with a burn function and call the specific token that I want to be burned? If possible, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new contract will still only allow you to call the same functions you could call on the token by executing a function with a regular account.

I mean, you will only be able to call the exposed functions such as:

```
 function totalSupply() constant returns (uint totalSupply);
 function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);
 function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
 function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
 function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success);
 function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining);
```

If you want to burn **your own** tokens (or tokens you have been approved) you could transfer them to the null address - address(0) - which will make them unavailable, BUT totalSupply will not get reduced, though.

Comment: So it is not possible to burn a deployed token that has no burn functionality implemented from start, thank you.